# Azure MobileApp API return 401 (Unauthorized) even after successful login with MobileServiceClient - UWP

Tags: azure, uwp, azure-active-directory, azure-mobile-services, zumo

**MobileApp Service**

I have an Azure MobileApp with App Service Authentication configured to "AAD Provider"

- Set client id and secret to AppID and Key of Azure AD Application created.
- Set IssuerUrl to https://sts.windows.net/b696XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXc4219dfb/
- Set allowed token audience to 
  https://mymobileapp.azurewebsites.net/**.auth/login/aad/callback** 
  and 
  https://mymobileapp.azurewebsites.net
- Set allowed external redirect urls to **{uri_schema}://easyauth.callback**

**Azure AD Application**

I have created azure ad application along with few custom roles in Manifest file for the MobileApp and added users to it.

**UWP App**

In my UWP package manifest declarations, i have added a protocol same as my "**{uri_schema}**" configured in MobileApp easy auth.

Creating MobileServiceClient as below

```
MobileServiceClient client = new MobileServiceClient("https://mymobileapp.azurewebsites.net/")
{
    CurrentUser = this.Container
                         .Resolve<IAuthenticator>()
                         .CurrentUser // This will be null for the first time
};
```

Then, login with below code and storing the credentials in vault.

```
this.CurrentUser = await this.app.ATTTMClient.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory, "{uri_schema}");
credential = new PasswordCredential("{vaultkey}", this.CurrentUser.UserId, this.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken);
this.Vault.Add(credential);
```

Till here, the authentication with user credential which I created in AD was successful and got stored in credential vault.

But, when I call any Mobile API methods using InvokeApiAsync as below, I'm getting following error:

```
HttpResponseMessage resp = await client.InvokeApiAsync(apiRoute, content, httpMethod, this.requestHeaders, parameters);
```

Error:
**The request could not be completed.  (Unauthorized)**

Sample Rest POST call:

> Method: GET, RequestUri: 'https://mymobileapp.azurewebsites.net/api/controller/action?key=value', Version: 2.0, Content: ,
>
> Headers:
>
> {
>
> Request-Id: f987cff8-XXXX-XXXX-XXX-374b8408ea53
>
> X-ZUMO-FEATURES: AG
>
> X-ZUMO-INSTALLATION-ID: e8d23287-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-b7885af589ef
>
> X-ZUMO-AUTH: eyJ0eXAiOiJKVXXXXXXXXXOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyXXXXXXXXXkOjFmNTlhZDI2MGJmZjVXXXXDBhZTllYXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX0dG1hdXNlZWFzLmF6dXJld2XXXZXMubmV0LyIXXXXXXXXXXXXzOi8vYXR0dG1hdXNlZWFzLmF6dXJld2Vic2l0ZXMubmV0LyIsImV4cCI6MTUXXXXXXXXXXTMzMTE2MDQwfQ.8fha-XymJSDEIxw22RSymW9T4XXXXXXXXWFh_zpF7ag
>
> User-Agent: ZUMO/4.0
>
> User-Agent: (lang=Managed; os=Windows Store; os_version=--; arch=X64; version=4.0.2.0)
>
> X-ZUMO-VERSION: ZUMO/4.0 (lang=Managed; os=Windows Store; os_version=--; arch=X64; version=4.0.2.0)
>
> ZUMO-API-VERSION: 2.0.0
>
> Cookie: ARRAffinity=c2ec7bad91771ba38a3XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX56cb5457cc94b47c79e2847
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip
>
> }

At this point, I'm refreshing the token which is successful but retrying the API call with refreshed token still fails with same error.

The only API Call (InvokeApiAsync) which is successful in my case is below while initializing roles after successful login:

```
user = (await client.InvokeApiAsync<User[]>("/.auth/me", HttpMethod.Get, null))?.FirstOrDefault();
```

What am I missing here? Why other API calls are failing with 401 code?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could figure out issue i was facing. 
In MobileApp API - AuthorizeAttribute's OnAuthorizationAsync method, I was trying to get Identity from AD for the API Call request and was failing with error followed by this code snippet.

```
var principal = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal;
if (principal != null)
{
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
    AzureActiveDirectoryCredentials identity;
    try
    {
         identity = await principal.GetAppServiceIdentityAsync<AzureActiveDirectoryCredentials>(actionContext.Request);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         logger.Error(ex, "Error while retrieving AD Identity");
         throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }
    ......
}
```

Error thrown from GetAppServiceIdentityAsync call:

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

**The solution that worked for me was to change "Minimum TLS version" to 1.0 from 1.2 in 
AppService --> Settings --> SSL Settings**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `ApiController` you are calling on the server side has the `[MobileAppController]` attribute for the authorization to work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Attribute is in place, Also one thing i would like add here is that this code is working fine for existing environments. I'm facing this issue only when i try to setup a new environment(different AD tenant). So there should not be any issue with Code but i must be missing some configuration either at AD or App Service or UWP Manifest.